# Creating a Typescript interface that can represent certain types

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, interface, typeorm

I'm trying to create a basic interface, with a 'type' property I want to be one of a group of types. When I try to use the interface to create an object with one of the types, I get error: *'a' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.*

```
export type Options = a | b | c | d | e;

interface Basic {
    id: string;
    type: Options;
    userId: string;
    organizationId: string;
    timestamp: string;
    data: string; //serialized string of the data based on the event type
}


export interface a {
    aProp1: boolean;
    aProp2: string;
}

export interface b {
    bProp1: number;
    bProp2: string;
}

export interface c {
    cProp1: boolean;
    cProp2: string;
}

export interface d {
    dProp1: boolean;
    dProp2: string;
    dProp3: string;
}

export interface e {
    eProp1: boolean;
}

const example: Basic = { id: "", userId: "", organizationId: "", timestamp: "", data: "", type:a }
```

Any idea how to implement this kind of interface, without using Typescript generics? (I'm using postgres with TypeOrm and T doesn't work well with it)

Thank you for any help!

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions

Comment: You don't assign `type` to be `a`, you assign "an a" to `type`. `{..., type { aProp1: true, aProp2: "hello" }`. In no way does this force `Basic` to have a specific `a` or `b` or whatever, and accessing `type` you still need to identify which type it is to use the properties. You would need to use generics for that.